# How to centralize forms validations in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I would like to centralize forms validation. I created a file: **src/schemas/schemas.js**.

On this file I'm placing all forms validations, for example:

```
export const schemaRegister = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup.string().required("Username is required").matches(/^[0-9a-z]+$/),
  password: yup.string().required("Password is required").min(8).otherValidations...,
  passwordConfirmation: yup.string()
    .required("Password confirmation is required")
    .oneOf([yup.ref("password"), null], "Passwords must match")
});

export const schemaLogin = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup.string().required("Username is required"),
  password: yup.string().required("Password is required").min(8).otherValidations...,
});

OTHER SCHEMAS
```

I have two doubts:

1. Is it ok to have all forms validations schemas in one single file (src/schemas/schemas.js)?
2. As you can see, in both schemas, I'm repeating

   ```
   password: yup.string().required("Password is required").min(8).otherValidations...
   ```

is there a way to avoid to repeat the code? Because I have other forms with some fields that have a complicated validation, so I would like to not repeat it

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid repetition. Lets say you want to use `schemaLogin` in `schemaRegister`. You can merge these schemas using `.shape` like this:

```
const schemaRegister = schemaLogin.shape({
                       passwordConfirmation: yup.string()
                      .required("Password confirmation is required")
                      .oneOf([yup.ref("password"), null], "Passwords must match")
});
```